# How to get the children-item in listItem of a listView (Titanium)?

Tags: titanium, listitem

I had defined an imageview in my layout for the individual items of a list, and they were set invisible. When I clicked a button, they will be show,but I can't get this action act. I want to achieve this effect. Here is my code:

```
//file:list_view_test.jade
Alloy    
    Window#win
        Button#btn(title = "Show" onClick = "show_the_image_view")

        ListView#list_view(defaultItemTemplate = "list_style")
            Templates
                ItemTemplate(name = "list_style")
                    View#item_view(bindId = "bind_item_view")
                        ImageView#image_view(bindId = "bind_image_view")

        ListSection
            ListItem(bind_item_view:backgroundImage = "/images/backgroundImage_1.png"
                     bind_image_view:image = "/images/unchecked_image.png")
            ListItem(bind_item_view:backgroundImage = "/images/backgroundImage_2.png"
                     bind_image_view:image = "/images/unchecked_image.png")

//file:list_view_test.stss
#item_view{
    width:100%;
    height:10% 
}

#image_view{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:20%;
    height:20%;

    visible:false
}

//file:list_view_test.coffee
show_the_image_view = ->
    if "Show" == $.btn.getTitle()
        $.btn.setTitle("Hide")
        //$.image_view.setVisible(true) (this code had been commented, cause it's wrong)
    else if "Hide" == $.btn.getTitle()
        $.btn.setTitle("Show")
        //$.image_view.setVisible(false) (this code had been commented, cause it's wrong)

$.list_view.addEventListener('itemclick', = (e) ->
    if e.itemIndex == 0
        //$.image_view.setImage('/images/checked_image.png') (this code had been commented, cause it's wrong)

    else if e.itemIndex == 1
        //$.image_view.setImage('/images/checked_image.png') (this code had been commented, cause it's wrong)
```

Is there anyone who has a good method to solve the problem?